# mssql_connect unable to connect to server

Tags: php, sql-server, debian

I'm trying to connect to a remote sql server database via php in our debian server.

```
<?php
// Some basic variables
$Server = "myservername";
$User = "myuser";
$Password = "mypwd";
$Database = "facts_sql";
// Connect to the database
$dbconnect = mssql_connect($Server,$User,$Password);
?>
```

And I got the error.

```
PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): message: Login failed for user ''. (severity 14) in /var/www/Information.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 14) in /var/www/Information.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: myservername:1433 in /var/www/Information.php on line 8
```

Are there any advices? Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL Server error log?  You want to check the State there and match up Severity 14 State =? with this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Comment: @SQLDBA Hi, thank you for answering. I cant access to the SQL server error log.